# macvlan - container not pingable from other devices on the phyiscal network

Tags: docker, docker-networking

Trying to understand how macvlan works and would like to be able to assign an IP number to a docker container and make it pingable from within my entire network.

My physical router has IP number 192.168.1.1 subnet mask is 255.255.255.0.

On my docker host I created a network like so:

```
sudo docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 --gateway=192.168.1.1 -o parent=enp0s3 -o macvlan_mode=bridge mynetwork
```

Then I started a container based on alpine and assigned it an IP number:

```
sudo docker container run -it --name alpine1 --network mynetwork --ip 192.168.1.223 alpine
```

In this container when I check the IP address I get:

```
inet 192.168.1.223/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
```

But, I cannot ping this container from any other phyiscal machine in my network.

I read somewhere that the parent interface on the host needs to be in promiscious mode?

So on the host I did this:

```
ip link set dev enp0s3 promisc on
```

But I am still not able to ping the container.

Any help in trying to understand this all would be really appreciated.

### Update

Based on the comments I was given I decided to test my setup directly on a physical server and all worked. I was able to ping phyiscal machines from within the container as well as ping the container from physical machines in the network.

So the problems I was having had to do with the fact that my initial test was on a container within a virtualbox vm. I still have not identified what the issue is there though.

Comment: fwiw: MACVLAN is smarter than this: it will use the NIC's Ethernet MAC filter list (which has a limited number of entries, something like ~ 20) to have the NIC filter adequately without promiscuous mode, unless this table gets full (=> automatic promiscuous, no need to set it). Your problem is elsewhere, and you should use debugging techniques to pinpoint where, especially using the tool tcpdump, both on host and container.

Comment: Just ran your setup and here it works. The only system that has problem (as expected with macvlan) is the host itself. All other systems in the network can reach the container. So you should check firewall settings etc (firewall + Docker = bad combo). Also check the environment's firewalling (especially if all your setup is virtualized within an hypervisor which restricts MAC addresses).

Comment: Thank you, your feedback was realy helpful. When I tested my setup directly on the physical server (no VM) I was able to ping the container from physical machines in the network as well as ping those physical machines from within the container.

Comment: Well I wrote what's the problem: "hypervisor which restricts MAC addresses".

Answer (score 0):

Since it is vm inside container scenario, you need to change the network setting in vbox from NAT->bridge and below that enable promisc to allow all.